# Various definitions of the tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

Let $M$ be a finite-dimensional smooth manifold with atlas $\mathcal A$ and $p\in M$. There are various *equivalent* definitions of the tangent space $T_pM$:

1. *approach via derivations:* the space of derivations of smooth functions: $C^\infty(M)\to \mathbb R$,
2. *approach via germs:* the space of derivations of the *germs* at $p$, $C^\infty_p\to\mathbb R$,
3. *velocity vector approach:* the set of curves $\sigma : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to M$ such that $\sigma(0)=p$, divided by an appropiate equivalence relation,
4. *physicists' approach*: set of functions $X_p: \mathcal A\to \mathbb R^n$ that take a coordinate chart and give coordinates relative to this chart, assigning them according to the transformation rule.
5. *algebraic geometers' approach*: the dual of $\mathfrak m_p/\mathfrak m_p^2$, where $\mathfrak m_p$ is the ideal of germs vanishing at $p$,

I wonder how one defines tangent space for different kinds of manifolds than smooth, especially:

- analytic/complex manifolds (i.e. one doesn't want to use partitions of unity as in 1.),
- $C^k$ manifolds for $1\le k<\infty$ (i.e. 5. is infinite dimensional),
- infinite-dimensional Banach manifolds.

Could you please provide references in which the above definitions are discussed? I would like to know which definitions are preferred (and to which are equivalent) in which contexts.

Comment: John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds does all the approaches except (as far as I've seen) not 5.

Comment: As far as i remember Lee's smooth manifold only did for algebraic approach and the just mention few others. However, i found a decent explanation of all approach in  Jeff Lee's manifolds

Comment: @Sou I agree - John Lee's book covers the algebraic approach and mentions others. It also mentions that the definition with germs works in the analytic/complex case. I'm looking for something explaining how these definitions tie together (or become irrelevant) in other categories than just $C^\infty$ manifolds. Unfortunately Jeff Lee's book doesn't cover other categories either...

Comment: I didn't know much about that but probably [Lang's book](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor) or [KMS](https://www.amazon.com/Natural-Operations-Differential-Geometry-Kolar/dp/3540562354) may help.